# Problem using writer.add_graph() on model class with multiple networks and methods which takes different inputs

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, tensorboard

I was trying to visualize a model, implemented as a Class, with several networks and methods, and each with different input. When I use writer.add_graph(), it returns NotImplementedError.

My model is for reinforcement learning, and it is something similar to the following pseudocode:

```
class MyModel():
  init
  self.network1 = torch.nn.DataParallel(some nn.Sequential)
  self.network2 = torch.nn.DataParallel(some nn.Sequential)
  self.network3 = torch.nn.DataParallel(some nn.Sequential)
  (... and more networks)

  def method1(self, x):
    v, r, p, e = self.network1(x)
    return v, r, p, e

  def method2(self, e):
    v, r, p, next_e = self.network2(e, a)
    return v, r, p, next_e

  def method3(self, x, y):
    pa = self.network3(x, y)
    return pa

# FYI: In training, loss = calculate_loss(array_of_vs, array_of_rs, array_of_ps, e, next_e, pa, a)
# but as far as I understand, the train part is independent of the writer.add_graph()
  
model_to_visualize = MyModel()

writer = SummaryWriter('some_dir')

dummyx = torch.ones(some_dims)
dummyy = torch.ones(some_dims)
dummye = torch.ones(some_dims)
dummya = torch.ones(some_dims)
dummydata = (dummyx, dummyy, dummye, dummya)

writer.add_graph(model_to_visualize, dummydata)
writer.close()
```

The question I wanted to ask is, is it actually not supported by writer.add_graph() to visualize these kind of structures?
If not, any recommendation on how I can do this?

For your information:

- There is no error when I tried writer.add_graph(MyModel().network1, dummyx), but this is not the thing I planned. I wanted to visualize the overall flow of all data.
- ray and DataParallel are used in the implementation. Not sure if it is related. I tried writer.add_graph in a separate script and the same error occurred.

---

Details of the error message:

```
Error occurs, No graph saved
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-d95ce6585e68>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/username/PybulletTest/auxs/testAddGraph/testAddGraph.py', wdir='/home/username/PybulletTest/auxs/testAddGraph')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/username/PybulletTest/auxs/testAddGraph/testAddGraph.py", line 196, in <module>
    writer.add_graph(model_to_visualize, dummydata)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py", line 724, in add_graph
    self._get_file_writer().add_graph(graph(model, input_to_model, verbose))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/_pytorch_graph.py", line 292, in graph
    raise e

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/_pytorch_graph.py", line 286, in graph
    trace = torch.jit.trace(model, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py", line 733, in trace
    return trace_module(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py", line 934, in trace_module
    module._c._create_method_from_trace(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 725, in _call_impl
    result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 709, in _slow_forward
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 175, in _forward_unimplemented
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Are you inheriting `nn.Module`?

Comment: Yes, I do. It should be class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):

Comment: Would it be possible to add a minimum working code instead of the psuedocode to reproduce the error?